# Importing a mMyQSL database using HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, import, heidisql

My MYSQL database is in .sql file format, I am trying to import it into MySQL using HeidiSQL. But, as I starting importation from the Load SQL file, the importation process is halted by this error message

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspondes to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘curdate()) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC’ at line 17

See the snapshot:

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn1tK.png)

Comment: Provide a part of your .SQL file (up to line 18 at least).

Comment: Prediction: `curdate()` mentioned in the error message is used as DEFAULT value for DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue :
I fixed it by removing DEFUALT CHARSET=utf8mb4 from my .sql file

Comment: Shown issue CANNOT be fixed by this way. You have had some another error message (I think it was "unknown charset/collation" due to old MySQL version).